# Set default value of Html.DropDownListFor from List ASP.Net

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, foreach, html.dropdownlistfor

I have this model

```
public class foo
{
   public foo()
   {
      this.barList = new List<bar>();
   }
   public string name { get; set; }
   public List<bar> barList { get; set; }
}

public class bar
{
   public string sample1 { get; set; }
   public string sample2 { get; set; }
   public string sample3 { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to display these values in view but I am not able to display the value that is supposedly be displayed in `Html.DropDownListFor`

Here is how I render it on my view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.barList)
{
  <div>
     @item.sample1
  </div>
  <div>
    @{
        var status = new SelectList(
        new List<SelectListItem>
        {
                            new SelectListItem {Text = "text1", Value = "value1"},
                            new SelectListItem {Text = "text2", Value = "value2"},
                            new SelectListItem {Text = "text3", Value = "value3"}
        }, "Value", "Text");
    }
     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => item.sample2, status, "-- Select -- ", new { @class = "w100 form-control" })
  </div>
  <div>
     @item.sample3
  </div>
}
```

What I am trying to do is set the selected value for the `DropDownList` to the value in the variable `sample2` on which value it matches on the select list. But somehow there is no value that is being selected when I try this code.

Comment: after "Text" in new List<selectlistitem> add, "-- selected --"

Comment: Put a breakpoint in Controller code and check what is the value of sample2.